# "To run this application, you must install missing frameworks for .NET"

Tags: .net, frameworks

At the moment I got a problem with my .NET 7.0 installation. I need version 6 or higher for the use of a specific application. After downloading de .NET 7.0 SDK environment in x64. I still get the error trying to run the application. I've been looking for an answer but haven't found the correct one. Maybe someone can help me with this?

After running my dotnet --info in the command prompt I get these environment settings:
[image]

Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, during installation I had a dialog that said I need 6.0.5 or higher to continue installation. The installation worked with the higher version that I chose, but when opening the program, I then got the same message, I then went down to 6.0.5. So I assume, that the easiest is to stay close to the version that is the minimum requirement.

Comment: Additinally, I think it is possible to have several .NET frameworks on the same computer.